# unable to open view in model popup mvc 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to render a view when user clicks on "Add New" button on the index page. I have an Action in the controller which handles Create post. Problem here is that i am not able to load the View. When i click "Add New" button, nothing happens. Can someone please point out what am i missing here?

This is how my Index view looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Add New Item',
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load('@Url.Action("Country/Create")');
            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $('#AddNew').click(function () {
            alert('Hello');
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>

<button id="AddNew" type="button">Add New</button>

<div id="dialog" style="overflow: hidden;">

</div>
```

Script references:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>


    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>

<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

--Solution--

I was missing jquery.ui.all.css reference.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: probably the way you provide controller and action to the Url.Action helper...Country/Create..try splitting this into two parameters. Also you might wan't to post your routes config. Also check in Firebug what happens when you click on the button.

Comment: @Asdfg: Does your controller action get called? What do you see in Firebug?

Comment: I see an error in firebug saying $("#dialog").dialog is not a function.

Comment: @Asdfg: That tells me that perhaps you are not including jQueryUI correctly. Make sure jQueryUI scripts and styles are appropriately linked in your document. **EDIT** You might want to make sure jQuery comes *before* jQueryUI in your script references.

Comment: Never thought the order matters. That did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: @Asdfg, seems to work in this example http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/APGcy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting your Javascript code between

```
$(document).ready(function () {
...
});
```

Comment: no luck. Somehow i dont know why but JS files are loaded after the Country/Create is executed. And i can see that in Firebug. No idea why is it doing that or if thats the problem.

Comment: I would bet your script references are in an master or layout page file and at the end of it?

Comment: They are in the layout file. I have updated the question with layout view.

Comment: i was missing jquery.ui.all.css reference

Answer (score 0):

```
I **think** your file order is wrong

jquery-1.5.1.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js

now other files
```

-------------I think your URL format is also wrong---------

```
@Url.Action("Action","Cortoller");
@Url.Action("Create","Country");
$(this).load('@Url.Action("Create","Country")');
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the help. I am still facing the problem that it is not opening the popup. It just renders that on the index page. No popup shows up.

Comment: the alert is working? If not, then your dialog.open() is not getting called

Comment: ok. Remove the alert and report what does Firebug say (on the Net tab) - does it make a call to your controller ?

Comment: are you sure this url is actually returning data, you can open firebug and see what error it is showing

Comment: Yes. It makes call to the controller and controller does return the view. View gets rendered as well. Only thing is that it is not Model view. It just renders withing the page inside the "dialot" div.

Comment: I changed @Url.Action as you suggested but still the same result. Since the Create View is being rendered, i am sure it is making a call. I put a breakpoint in there and it hits the breakpoint too so i dont think there is a problem in there. Somehow the view is not opening in popup. It is getting rendered inside "dialog" div.

Comment: could you explain what do you mean by "pop up" and "dialog Div"

Comment: I think somehow my view gets rendered before JS files are loaded.

Comment: @PraveenPrasad let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1308/discussion-between-asdfg-and-praveen-prasad)